Is it possible to access Environment Variable in PowerApps using Typescript
just want to ask if is it possible to get the environment variables of a solution from powerapps using react typescript and store it to my .envi?
I just need to access and store the componentID, componentSecret and componentExchangeURL

@Allenzier, I don't understand what do you mean by componentId, componentSecret and how it's linked to powerbi-embedded? Please rephrase the question in detailed with what your final goal is and what you're, so I can try to help
